# Why Pouchdb sync filter throws 404 not found error

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Does anyone know why I would get error using filters but hardcoded function works?

I am using PouchDB, pouchdb-authentication

When I use this Sync and login with uName hard coded for testing:

```
const db = new PouchDB('http://admin:pass@<couch_ip>:5984/dvir/', {skip_setup: true});

db.logIn('01WIMA', 'uName', function (err, response) {
 //do stuff here
}).then((result) => {

const dvirStoreData = new PouchDB("dvir-StoreData");

dvirStoreData.sync(db, {
    live: true, 
    retry: true,
    auto_compaction: true
    ,filter: 'app/by_user',
    query_params: { "user": "uName" }        
  });
});
```

With Filter doc:

```
dvirStoreData.put({
  "_id": "_design/app",
  
  "filters": {
    "by_user": "function(doc, req) { return doc._id === '_design/app' || return doc.user === req.query.user; }.toString()"
  }
})
```

I get error:

GET http://<couchdb_ip>/dvir/_changes?style=all_docs&filter=app%2Fby_user&user=01WIMA&since=0&limit=100 404 (Object Not Found)

This seems to work if I hardcode the filter:

```
dvirStoreData.sync(db, {
    live: true, 
    retry: true,
    auto_compaction: true
    ,filter: function (doc) { return doc._id === "_design/app" || doc.user === '01WIMA'; }
  })
```

Comment: Hardcoded filter with > "date" works also. but not when referring to filter in data. I find it weird that the data is key of "filters" (plural) and option refers to it as "filter:" (singular)

Comment: @rajagp do you know